# I have a url getting XY in json from php, The result is like [{"status":"ok","data":{"latitude":0.625,"longitude":0.855}}]. End result is "undefined"

Tags: html, jquery, json

I have a url getting XY in json from php, The result is like `[{"status":"ok","data":{"latitude":0.625,"longitude":0.855}}]`. End result is "undefined"

```html
<body>
    <div class="GPSData"></div>

    <script> 
        $.getJSON('http://api.alqimma.com.sa/index.php?key=??&type=live&vehicle=1865',
        function (json) {
           var mydata = `<b> ${json.longitude}, ${json.latitude} </b>`;
           console.log(mydata);
           $(".GPSData").html(mydata);
        });
    </script>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the structure of the JSON response, the references you use are invalid. First of all, the response appears to be an array (`[...]`) of one object. Within that object, the `longitude` and `latitude` properties are within the `data` structure.

So instead of using

```js
           var mydata = `<b> ${json.longitude}, ${json.latitude} </b>`;
```

using this seems to make more sense:

```js
           var mydata = `<b> ${json[0].data.longitude}, ${json[0].data.latitude} </b>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is what's causing your issue but I spotted an issue. You didn't include backticks on the line where you're creating your string. You also missed a closing `</b>` tag.

```
$.getJSON('https://api.alqimma.com.sa/index.php?key=??&type=live&vehicle=1865', function (json) {
    var mydata = `<b>${json.longitude}, ${json.latitude}</b>`;
    console.log(mydata);
    $(".GPSData").html(mydata);
});
```